# Model selection in SAS surveyreg analysis of complex surveys

Tags: model-selection, sas

What are model selection methods are applicable in this setting?

Is it possible to calculate AIC or BIC with SAS's `surveyreg` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, but you can refer two SAS macro programs:

[A SAS® MACRO FOR PERFORMING BACKWARD SELECTION IN PROC SURVEYREG](http://www.lexjansen.com/mwsug/2006/Statistics_DataAnalysis/SD10.pdf)
[SAS® Model Selection Macros for Complex Survey Data Using PROC SURVEYLOGISTIC/SURVEYREG](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2011/stats/MWSUG-2011-SA02.pdf)

Hope it helpful.

Comment: Thanks! in fact I had written SAS macros to do forward and backward selection as well. I'd like to be able to prevent over-fitting in the model building process. Is the inability to compute AIC/BIC quantities due to the nature of complex survey analysis, or is this due simply to yet-to-be-developed theory?

Comment: According to my pretty blur memory, Mplus may have AIC and BIC for some models based on survey data. You can take a look at its website: 

http://www.statmodel.com/

There is a discussion forum on the website. You can post this question, and Dr. Muthen (the developer) will answer you. Good luck!